# angular component doesn't get garbage collected

Tags: angular, mapbox-gl-js

i have been working with a project involving loading a lazy loaded module which contains a a map component.

expected behaviour is that when navigate to other modules or children components, the map component should gets destroyed, leaving nothing behind in memory.
since it's container component got destroyed !

what happens is that the container component in this case `customer-list` gets destroyed and get garbage collected but the map component still in memory with its service
you navigate back to the `customer-list`, a new instance of the map component along with the map service get initiated causing a rise in memory usage overtime when you navigate through the app different pages, because the map component doesn't get destroyed or garbage collected, reducing performance significantly over time.

[image]

here's a reproducing [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mapbox-with-lazyloading)

Comment: did you find the cause?

Comment: @user12163165 i don't actually remember, that's so old and old version of angular but let me tell you to make sure that you unsubscribe off any subscribers you have on your components and so, sorry but switched to vue long time ago :)